# how to control speed of worker thread(secondary thread) in android

Tags: android, multithreading, timertask

I am making a ECG graph display android application and extending  surfaceView class and implement SurfaceHolder. Callback and using  worker thread to lock canvas and and unlock as very common in game loop.

my class which extend surfaceView have draw function which draw line and this function is called by secondary thread to draw on lock canvas.

now my problem is that speed of drawing graph is so high. how i can control the speed of drawing .or can't we control control worker thread speed ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you even Google this? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked on ECG sensor before and I am pretty sure you can set a sampling rate in the sensor. Try decreasing the sampling rate and your application will automatically behave as you want.

Otherwise you can also take a look at a thread.sleep() method or use timer class and timer.schedule() method to run some code in specific intervals.

Comment: thanx Milanix and ta... actually my senior is not allowing me to use sleep in code. milanix i want to ask you whatever class i am use is correct for the ECG application.....or can you post some code sample

Comment: Get another job with better seniors if this Sleep() ban is general. OTOH, ECG displays really ought to have accurate timings.

Comment: I have already mentioned about sampling rate, please consult your sensors documentation for it. I don't think it's good idea to control that in your application. That way you will be skipping some important ECG feeds. Why are you creating your own graphs when there are already community recognized graphing libraries available. Why not try using AndroidPlot library with XYPlot implementation.

Comment: i am not using library because my boss is not allowing me to use external library. he want that i build application with generic classes.

Comment: @Milanix my aim to plot the ECG graph with given values. i can;t use sleep() or any external library.but i can use timer . I am confused where to use this timer ? can i use the timer to control the Secondary thread of surface view class or is there a method to control thread.i am requesting you if you can please post sample code or architecture/flow of your program..

Comment: This will be the last time I will say that please use sampling rate. I am not sure how my plotting will help you but, here you go http://pastebin.com/kCipqnB4